# Best way to find proportion of rows where condition is true for group_by

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

Say I have a dataframe in R - this example is made up for illustration purposes.

Variable 1 `weather` can take on value `Rain` or `Shine`.

Variable 2 `sport` can take on value `Basketball` or `Football`.

I want to find out a relationship between the variables, so I decide to summarize what proportion of rainy days was I playing basketball vs. football.

I am currently doing something like.

```
data %>%
group_by(weather, sport) %>%
summarize(
 percentage = n() / totalDaysWithThisWeather(data, weather)
)
```

```
totalDaysWithThisWeather <- function(df, weather) {
  return (
    df %>%
      filter(weather == weather) %>% 
      nrow()
  )
}
```

Is there a more organic way to do this and more generally extract this type of data about the representation of each group in the larger dataframe in the `group_by` to ``summarize``` step? This way seems very roundabout and inefficient.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  count(weather, sport) %>%
  group_by(weather) %>%
  mutate(percentage  = prop.table(n))
```

`count` would give number of rows for each `weather` and `sport` and for each unique `weather` value we calculate the proportion of sports played with `prop.table`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  count(weather, sport) %>%
  group_by(weather) %>%
  mutate(percentage  = proportions(n))
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like R, relative to other programming languages, is a lot about just understanding what tools you have at your disposal because of the amount of libraries and packages available - what's the best way in your opinion of becoming fluent in these tools? I find the R documentation to be pretty poor and unhelpful.